# Catch error messages in script mode

Tags: scripting, debugging, command-line

For debugging purposes, I wrote a function which should log the error message to a file. It does not work and I cannot see why this is the case. Here is the function:

```
execFailureQ[expr_] := Head[expr] == "execFailure";

safeExec[expr_, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{res, err, logF, quitCode},
   res = EvaluationData[Evaluate[expr]];
   If[res["Success"], Return[res["Result"]]];
   err = StringRiffle[ToString /@ res["Messages"]];
   logF = OptionValue["logFile"];
   If[logF != None, WriteString[logF, err <> "\n"]];
   quitCode = OptionValue["quitCode"];
   If[quitCode != None, Quit[quitCode]];
   Return[execFailure[err]];
];
SetAttributes[safeExec, HoldFirst];
Options[safeExec] = {"logFile" -> None, "quitCode" -> None};
```

In the script, it is used like this:

```
logFile = OpenWrite["test.log"];
SetOptions[safeExec, "logFile"->logFile, "quitCode"->1];
safeExec[Export["wrong?file*name.xlsx", JuliaSetPlot[0.365 - 0.37 I]]];
WriteString[logFile, "Done.\n"];
```

When I save the last four lines above in a file "test.m" and run it via

```
"C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.0\math.exe" -noprompt -script test.m
```

then I would expect that there is a file "test.log" with the error message "could not open "wrong?file*name.xlsx"" or similar, however, there is only "Done." written out.

What am I doing wrong? What would be good practise to use Mathematica in script mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

Use `===` and `=!=` to test for the equality of strings. `==` and `!=` is for mathematical equality and won't evaluate to `True` or `False` for symbols:

```
x != "asd"
(* x != "asd" *)
```

This is likely causing your code to fail.

When the first argument of `If` is neither `True` not `False` and the fourth argument (look it up!) isn't present, it does not evaluate:

```
If[1, a]
(* If[1, a] *)

If[1, a, b, c]
(* c *)

If[x == y, foo]
(* If[x == y, foo] *)
```

Another problem is that you use the head `execFailure` (a symbol) but then test for `"execFailure"` (a string). This isn't used in your test script, but be aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, this code does the job (I believe):

```
execFailureQ[expr_] := MatchQ[expr, _execFailure];

safeExec[expr_, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{res, err, logF, quitCode},
   res = EvaluationData[Evaluate[expr]];
   If[res["Success"], Return[res["Result"]]];
   err = StringRiffle[ToString /@ res["MessagesText"], ", \n"];
   logF = OptionValue["logFile"];
   If[logF =!= None, WriteString[logF, err <> "\n"]];
   quitCode = OptionValue["quitCode"];
   If[quitCode =!= None, Quit[quitCode]];
   Return[execFailure[err]];
];
SetAttributes[safeExec, HoldFirst];
Options[safeExec] = {"logFile" -> None, "quitCode" -> None};
```

Thanks for pointing the problems out!